# Domain to ViewModel Design?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am wondering about the best Design for the following.  I have Domain Models something like:

```
public class Car
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   //Other common properties removed for Brevity
}
```

In my Domain model then I also have models for Fuel specific cars which inherit from Car so something like:

```
public class DieselCar : Car
{
   public bool RunOnBioDiesel { get; set; }
   //other diesel specific properties removed for brevity
}

public class PetrolCar : Car
{
   public int NoSparkplugs { get; set; }
   //other petrol specific properties removed for brevity
}
```

On my view currently I just have a common Car View Model.  Some common properties are used and then depending on which Fuel Type I render a partial view for either Diesel or Petrol - again this Partial view just takes the complete CarView Model as there are common properties on each partial view as well.

However rather than map multiple properties from view model to domain in my controller and then domain to view model in my view model builder I am wanting to take adavantage of automapper to do this.

However I think that would mean having a something like the below in AutomapperBootstrapper (and I'm not sure this would even work correctly??)

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Car, CarViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.DieselCar, CarViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.PetrolCar, CarViewModel>();

Mapper.CreateMap<CarViewModel, Domain.Car>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CarViewModel, Domain.DieselCar>();
Mapper.CreateMap<CarViewModel, Domain.PetrolCar>();
```

I am thinking the other way is in my view model to have three different classes for CommonCarFields, DieselCarFields and PetrolCarFields and then in the CarViewModel constructor new each one of those classes and then Map each Domain model to its corresponding class on the viewmodel and vice versa in AutoMapper?

Perhaps anyone can suggest a better way of doing this even than I am missing?

Comment: I would try the dynamic mapping where you don't have to configure mappings in advance.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - have you got a link to an example of this Wiktor or can you elaboarte with an example in an answer?

Comment: Might want to rethink your domain model.  Using inheritance will blow up as soon as you try to add additional features.

Comment: @Cerad - not sure what you mean?  Can you give an example of how you think this would 'blow up'?

Comment: Well, what if you wanted to track the type of transmission (manual vs automatic).

Comment: @Cerad then I would put that as a property on the common domain object.  If it is not displayed on view anywhere I would mark it as ignore with automapper

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat: `Mapper.DynamicMap( source, destination )`. This doesn't involve creating maps in advance.

Comment: Object inheritance here is a bad idea as @Cerad already mentioned, use object composition.

Comment: @Cerad: if all common properties are in the base class and there are only few child classes with their own specific properties then why it is supposed to "blow up"?

Comment: I think we are getting a bit off topic here.  But your question has two major ifs in it.  I suspect the actual domain might be a tad more complicated.

Comment: @WiktorZychla in example try to add compressor property, both diesel and petrol can have it, but don't have to, so you can't add it to Car class (SRP violation). In class inheritance you would have to violate DRY to add it (unless it works differently), with object composition you simply add to car properties it needs.

Comment: @RafałŁużyński: if they have it as a property but not necessarily "contain" it (it is optional) then you don't violate SRP by having it in the base class. The property is there, the instance can just be null.

Comment: @WiktorZychla but such inheritance is not giving us any advantage, we still have to assign that instance somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if I needed every property in my domain model in my view.  I tend to flatten data when sending it to a view, or sending it over-the-wire.  I've found in both cases, if you're keeping identical object graphs in both your domain and view models, then religiously mapping between the two, you're probably doing something wrong somewhere.

Whenever I've built an application-centric app, this direct mapping never happens naturally.  In data-centric apps, on the other hand, I often see the structure of the database being (incorrectly) forced up through every layer.